# takeWhile for an infinite IO list

Tags: functional-programming, frege

I'm trying to consume an infinite list which may contain elements of type:

`IO (Either Throwable a)`

- I'm only interested in consuming elements of type `Right`.
- List is sorted. `Right` elements are always first and then `Left` elements

The problem is that the implementation I'm using is wrong because the function `sequence` evaluates the infinite list, so function never ends.

```
takeWhileRight :: [IO (Either Throwable a)] -> IO [(Either Throwable a)]
takeWhileRight list = do
  unwrappedList <- sequence $ list -- BANG!!
  return $ takeWhile isRight $ unwrappedList

isRight :: (Either Throwable a) -> Bool
isRight x = case x of
  Right x -> true
  Left  x -> false
```

Any ideas about how to consume that list properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this doesn't work with `sequence`

You need to do something like

```
takeWhileRight (x:xs) = do
  y <- x
  case y of
      Right -> (y:) <$> takeWhileRight xs
      Left  -> pure []
takeWhileRight [] = pure  []
```

(Untested.)

Note that the first IO action that gives a `Left` will still have to be run. This is unavoidable.